# Перенаправление по дате с помощью htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, дата, редирект

Как перенаправить с помощью *htaccess* пользователя с адреса
`site.com/son/pre/01-12-2021/` на страницу `site.com/son/pre/`, если эта дата уже прошла?

Т.е. если указана дата меньше чем сегодня. Например. в адресе указано что 1-е число, а сегодня например 2,3,4,5 или 31 декабря, или вообще год другой. Главное чтобы не заходить в *htaccess* и не менять сегодняшнюю дату каждый день.

В условии нужно учесть `/son/pre/`

Нужно как-то разложить дату по переменным и потом сравнить с `TIME_YEAR`, `TIME_MON`, `TIME_DAY`.
Я просто не силён в регулярных выражениях. Помогите пожалуйста.
Такое вообще возможно реализовать?

Comment: никак, перенаправить в пхп, который проверит дату, и если не подходит, то перенаправит в индекс

Comment: А что, разве нельзя никак разобрать по переменным дату и потом сравнить с текущими днём месяцем и годом в виде TIME_YEAR, TIME_MON, TIME_DAY ?

Answer (score 0):

оказалось все довольно просто, должно работать как-то так

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}  -gt%3%2%1
RewriteRule ^son/pre/(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d{4})/?$  /son/pre      [R=301]
```

Comment: Не работает, кидает на главную страницу. Кстати, а можно внести небольшую правку в условие /son/pre/, - /son/ постоянно, а /pre/ может меняться на например другие /son/pri/ или /son/pro/ или  вообще /son/pro/pre/. Но /son/ и дата в адресе обязательны.

Comment: в другом месте значит кидает где-то. мб вы в конец файла дописали? у меня работает.